# Amazon MWS PHP Mark order as Shipped - Submit Order Fulfillment with Shipping with XML in variable

Tags: php, amazon-mws

### How to mark an order shipped in Amazon MWS by using an XML feed - using the correct endpoint, service, version and headers?

This was the question, and it took me 3 days to manage it since amazon api is extremely chaotic, documentation is medieval, and most critical information like proper endpoint addresses to submit any particular information is a mystery to find. I was only able to create it by imitating a request at scratchpad, randomly testing sections, combining the examples for other requests for totally different sections and actions. Submitting XML feeds is the only way to manage your orders currently.

So, this may help someone.

Comment: Hi, from where I can find available shipping methods?

Comment: i cant say anything helpful now. Has been too long since i had to deal with this amazon issue.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make below simple code work :

```
                        $param = array();
                        $param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = 'YOURKEY'; 
                        $param['Action']           = 'SubmitFeed'; 
                        $param['Merchant']         = 'YOURMERCHANTID'; 
                        $param['FeedType']         = '_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_'; 
                        $param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
                        $param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
                        $param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
                        $param['Version']          = '2009-01-01'; 
                        $param['MarketplaceId.Id.1']    = 'MARKETPLACEID';
                        $param['PurgeAndReplace']    = 'false';

                        $secret = 'YOURSECRETKEY';

                        $url = array();
                        foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

                            $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
                            $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
                            $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
                        }

                        $amazon_feed='<?xml version="1.0"?>
                            <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
                            <Header>
                            <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                            <MerchantIdentifier>YOURMERCHANTID</MerchantIdentifier>
                            </Header>
                            <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
                            <Message>
                            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                            <OrderFulfillment>
                            <AmazonOrderID>YOUROWNORDERIDHERE</AmazonOrderID>
                            <FulfillmentDate>'.$param['Timestamp'].'</FulfillmentDate>
                            <FulfillmentData>
                            <CarrierName>TRACKINGCONAMEHERE</CarrierName>
                            <ShippingMethod>TRACKINGCONAMEORMETHODHERE</ShippingMethod>
                            <ShipperTrackingNumber>TRACKINGNOHERE</ShipperTrackingNumber>
                            </FulfillmentData>
                            </OrderFulfillment>
                            </Message>
                            </AmazonEnvelope>';


                        sort($url);

                        $arr   = implode('&', $url);

                        $sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
                        $sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
                        $sign .= '/Feeds/'.$param['Version'].'' . "\n";
                        $sign .= $arr;

                        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
                        $httpHeader     =   array();
                        $httpHeader[]   =   'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
                        $httpHeader[]   =   'Content-Type: application/xml';
                        $httpHeader[]   =   'Content-MD5: ' . base64_encode(md5($amazon_feed, true));
                        $httpHeader[]   =   'Expect:';
                        $httpHeader[]   =   'Accept:';              

                        $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

                        $link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Feeds/".$param['Version']."?";
                        $link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
                        echo '<br>';
                        echo($link); //for debugging - you can paste this into a browser and see if it loads.
                        echo '<br>';
                        $ch = curl_init($link);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $amazon_feed); 
                        $response = curl_exec($ch);
                        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);
```

Gives the below output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><SubmitFeedResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">SubmitFeedResult>FeedSubmissionInfo>FeedSubmissionId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FeedSubmissionId><FeedType>_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_</FeedType><SubmittedDate>2014-09-09T00:36:29+00:00</SubmittedDate><FeedProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</FeedProcessingStatus></FeedSubmissionInfo>/SubmitFeedResult>ResponseMetadata>RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></SubmitFeedResponse><?xml version="1.0"?><SubmitFeedResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/"><SubmitFeedResult><FeedSubmissionInfo><FeedSubmissionId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FeedSubmissionId>FeedType>_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_</FeedType><SubmittedDate>2014-09-09T00:36:29+00:00</SubmittedDate>FeedProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</FeedProcessingStatus></FeedSubmissionInfo>/SubmitFeedResult>ResponseMetadata>RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></SubmitFeedResponse>
```

Comment: Hi, from where I can find api supported shipping methods?