# Amazon MWS _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ Not Submitting

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

I have looked at this so long to find whats wrong with my XML structure but maybe now cant see it for looking at it. Can anyone help?

When I run this is in the Scratchpad, after trying to submit, I keep getting "We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderFulfillment>
      <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
      <AmazonOrderID>XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX</AmazonOrderID>
      <FulfillmentDate>2014-12-19T15:09:51+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <CarrierName>FedEx</CarrierName>
        <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
        <ShipperTrackingNumber>XXXXXXXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

this was taken from the example feed on the sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>123456</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <OrderFulfillment>
      <AmazonOrderID>204-3070364-1550743</AmazonOrderID>
      <FulfillmentDate>2014-07-22T23:59:59-07:00</FulfillmentDate>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <CarrierName>Contact Us for Details</CarrierName>
        <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>42197908407194</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I have also removed "Update" as I wasn't sure this was required in the XSD.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Jason

Comment: try new DateTime('0 Days', new DateTimeZone('UTC')) for FulfillmentDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OperationType` is part of `Message`, not part of `OrderFulfillment`. Switch lines 10 and 11 so that like this:

```
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<OrderFulfillment>
```

Comment: This has it sorted. Many thanks. It was driving me mad. Best of festive cheer. :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this links [Amazon MWS Forum](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2523749) | [Similar Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735271/amazon-mws-php-mark-order-as-shipped-submit-order-fulfillment-with-shipping-wi)

Only thing I can notice is the FulfillmentDate

```
<FulfillmentDate>2014-07-22T23:59:59-07:00</FulfillmentDate>
```